# How to pass multiple arguments through React Context (from Consumer to Provider)?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am creating a simple app using create-react-app

And was exploring using `React Context API` to pass few stuff from one component to another component.

**Spice.js**

```
const spiceList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Spice 11',
    name: require('./images/spice1.jpeg')
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Spice 22',
    name: require('./images/spice2.jpeg')
  }
```

];

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to Spices</h1>

 <SpiceContext.Provider value={'Masala'} imgSrc={img3}>
    <SpiceList/>
 </SpiceContext.Provider>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

}
}

export default Spice;

**Consumer in SpiceList** Where I plan to retrieve multiple attributes instead of a single value attribute.

> How this could be achieved? Thanks

```
<>
                    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
                    <SpiceContext.Consumer>
                      {spiceContext=> <img src={spiceContext.value} alt={spiceContext.title}/>
                      }
                    </SpiceContext.Consumer>
      </>
```

**SpiceContext**

```
import React from 'react';
```

const SpiceContext = React.createContext(null);

export default SpiceContext;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your object to share.

```
const myOptions = [
  {
    key: 1,
    title: 'Title',
    other: 'other',
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    title: 'Title',
    other: 'other',
  }
];
```

Then pass it down.

```
return (
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome to Spices</h1>

     <SpiceContext.Provider value={myOptions} imgSrc={img3}>
        <SpiceList/>
     </SpiceContext.Provider>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Then you will receive those in the same way:

```
<h1>{props.title}</h1>
<SpiceContext.Consumer>
  {(options) => (
    <>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <img key={option.key} src={option.other} alt={option.title}/>
      ))}
    </>
  )}
</SpiceContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: In my case, myOptions is a Array of Object. Kindly suggest in that case.

Comment: If you have a list to pass down I supose you will .map this list and render a list of <SpliceItems  /> ?